# How to use the optimization toolbox in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I get an error when I try to use optimization functions from MATLAB R2014a. The error message is:

> Undefined function 'gaoptimset' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Apparently, you need to use arguments of type other than `cell`. Study of this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/gaoptimset.html might help you. To get more sophisticated answer, you need provide more information. Study this link to learn how to ask good question at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @brainkz, I editted the question, please take a look at it!

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before using them. Removed unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, study [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/gaoptimset.html) more thoroughly. I dare to guess that you put some values into curly brackets because they were in curly brackets in documentation. However, Matlab explicitly states that:

> Values in {} denote the default value

So, first of all you need to remove them. Then, you need to remove `tournamentSize`, `0.1` and `0.8` in the arguments since the value after `'SelectionFcn'`, `'MutationFcn'` and `'CrossoverFcn'` should be just a function handle. So, you end up with:

```
options = gaoptimset('CreationFcn', @PopFunction,...
                     'PopulationSize',50,...
                     'Generations',100,...
                     'PopulationType', 'bitstring',... 
                     'SelectionFcn',@selectiontournament,...
                     'MutationFcn',@mutationuniform,...
                     'CrossoverFcn', @crossoverarithmetic,...
                     'EliteCount',2,...
                     'StallGenLimit',100,...
                     'PlotFcns',@gaplotbestf,...  
                     'Display', 'iter');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried your method, it is not right. I got the error like this:"Undefined function 'gaoptimset' for input arguments of
type 'function_handle'."

Comment: @Poppy strange, my Matlab compiles with no problem, check if you have the Optimization toolbox by typing `ver`

Comment: @brainkz your MATLAB probably does not compile, unless you explicitly run it through the MATLAB compiler. MATLAB is an interpreted language, therefore it can run commands off the command line without have to compile.

Comment: @Adriaan as you wish)

Comment: @sorry, if the code provided in my answer does not work in your Matlab, then, I can't do anything.

Comment: @Poppy I have no idea about your code. I just pointed out to brainkz that MATLAB is an interpreted language, i.e. his comment about the code "compiling" is most likely incorrect, he probably meant the code runs.

Comment: @Poppy I don't know, Matlab 2014b was installed on my computer by company where I had internship. You can ask Mathworks customer support if your copy of Matlab is official. Otherwise you might need to find another copy or purchase one.

Comment: @Poppy the function is part of the Global Optimization Toolbox (as shown on the docs link in brainkz's answer, in the menu on the left side)

Comment: @brainkz, Maybe I should install another new version Matlab. Many thanks!

Comment: @Poppy no problem. But this is not related to the *version* of MATLAB. Various versions can have various toolboxes, fairly independently. You need to install this toolbox for your existing copy of MATLAB (or using another function).

Comment: @Poppy I assume that if your existing license doesn't contain it, then you have to purchase it from MathWorks.